# Problems with accessing Apache 2.2 server from outside the firewall

Tags: apache-http-server, firewall, port-forwarding, isp

I've done everything [this tutorial](http://lifehacker.com/124212/how-to-set-up-a-personal-home-web-server?tag=softwarefeature#3) told me to set up an Apache 2.2 HTTP server, and then forwarded port 80 to the machine the server is on.

However I'm not getting a response back when I try to connect to the server through my fully updated Netgear router. Everything works when I just type in the local IP address of the server machine, and yet I don't get a response when I try to connect to the external IP address (which should redirect to the working local IP address).

I'm not sure if this is a problem with my ISP, Apache Server settings, or Firewall.

**How do I find and fix this problem?**

---

LOGS:

**After successfully connecting from inside the firewall I get this log in the "error.txt" file:**

```
[Sat Feb 25 03:09:23 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.7] client denied by server configuration: C:/Users/Griffin/.htaccess
[Sat Feb 25 03:09:23 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.7] (OS 5)Access is denied.  : Cannot map GET / HTTP/1.1 to file
[Sat Feb 25 03:09:23 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.7] (OS 5)Access is denied.  : Cannot map GET / HTTP/1.1 to file
[Sat Feb 25 03:09:23 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.7] (OS 5)Access is denied.  : Cannot map GET / HTTP/1.1 to file
[Sat Feb 25 03:09:23 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.7] (OS 5)Access is denied.  : Cannot map GET / HTTP/1.1 to file
[Sat Feb 25 03:09:23 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.7] (OS 5)Access is denied.  : Cannot map GET / HTTP/1.1 to file
[Sat Feb 25 03:09:23 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.7] (OS 5)Access is denied.  : Cannot map GET / HTTP/1.1 to file
[Sat Feb 25 03:09:23 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.7] (OS 5)Access is denied.  : Cannot map GET / HTTP/1.1 to file
[Sat Feb 25 03:09:23 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.7] (OS 5)Access is denied.  : Cannot map GET / HTTP/1.1 to file
[Sat Feb 25 03:09:23 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.7] (OS 5)Access is denied.  : Cannot map GET / HTTP/1.1 to file
[Sat Feb 25 03:09:23 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.7] (OS 5)Access is denied.  : Cannot map GET / HTTP/1.1 to file
[Sat Feb 25 03:09:23 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.7] File does not exist: C:/Users/Griffin/favicon.ico
```

**And this in the "access.txt" file:**

```
192.168.1.7 - Griffin [25/Feb/2012:03:09:23 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1707
192.168.1.7 - Griffin [25/Feb/2012:03:09:23 -0800] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 209
```

**No new logs show up after attempting to connect to the server from a VPN**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you are testing your web server from outside your home network (you cannot go in the front of a firewall from behind it).

Also, try disabling any local firewalls on your web-server and test again.

Comment: I connected to a VPN (HotSpotShield) to get outside the Firewall, and then tried again. Still same result -_-. There's no local firewalls running either.

Comment: Can you review your web servers log files? I am not familiar with Apache on Windows, but in *nix land they are located in /var/log/apache2/

Comment: Also, if your web server is hosting more than one site (virtual hosts), you will need to add your ip address to the vhost you are using if you are not using a domain name. Example: `ServerAlias mysite.com www.mysite.com localhost 109.234.234.12`

Comment: I added the logs above, none show up when I try to connect through a VPN. Also, I'm using Windows and don't know what a virtual host is or why I would need it.